# Insert a record on behalf of system or another user

Tags: apex, deployment, user

It seems that when I deploy code to production and run apex to insert new records - these records are created from my name.

And it triggers some other processes that change data based on record creator. Example, if I'm adding a comment to a case it changes owner from a queue (custom process). And apparently I can't use `System.runAs`.

Is it possible to perform actions on behalf of system or another user (e.g. I'll create System User). What is the best practice (e.g. one person is always performing deployment)?

Comment: One person/User performing deployments? Im not sure if it makes any difference, really. Performing action on behalf of other users, yes! From UI, using Setup -> Users -> specfiic user -> Login. From Apex `System.runAs`. You mentioned you can't use the latter, I wonder why?

Comment: Mahmood, `System.runAs` is only good for tests. Not valid on regular apex.

Comment: @Sebastian Yup, i know, thanks nevertheless. Just forgot that in hurry. I wanted to edit the comments but denied as comments are only editable within five minutes of their post.

Comment: Btw if you batch and insert a record using flows and use wait component, record is inserted by "Automated process" user. It's pity there's nothing similar for Apex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to have a dedicated user for deployment and data upload.

We had used custom settings to avoid trigger from firing and used to add that user in setting. You could also add condition in workflows and processes to not fire for the deployment user.

From documentation:

> You can use runAs only in test methods. The original system context is started again after all runAs test methods complete.

Also you can login as a specific user if logging as any user is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need to create records as part of deployment?
Anyway, it's best practice to have some bypass functionality that give you option to disable trigger/workflow/validation per user/profile.
Still , even if you turn off trigger/workflow/validation, if you insert records you will see your name as the creator.

You might "login as" other user if you want to insert data on behalf, but I'm not recommend so. If it's the task of  user to insert the records- then he should do it by himself.

Answer (score 0):

You still cannot run as any user, but as of [Spring ’23, you can now explicitly run SOQL/DML `as user` (current user) or `as system`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_enforce_usermode.htm).

```
Account acc = new Account(Name='test');
insert as user acc;
```

However, I believe the record would still show as `Created By`/ `Updated By` the current user, even in system mode.